# react-slick: Import CSS from slick-carousel fails

Tags: reactjs, react-slick, css-import

React beginner here. My app uses create-react-app, and I'm pulling in [react-slick](https://github.com/akiran/generator-react-slick) for a carousel. I'm trying to follow the directions that are provided in the setup for react-slick, but the following doesn't work for me:

`@import "~slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
@import "~slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";`

I get the following error:

`./src/components/Homepage.scss
Module not found: Can't resolve '~slick-carousel/slick/slick.css' in '/Users/simon/Dev/frischideas/site-new/src/components'`

It works if I add the css to index.html from the CDN, but I'd rather avoid that network call, as I believe it's affecting the rendering of the page on initial load.

I tried following the [instructions](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-a-stylesheet) for configuring create-react-app to use relative paths, but that wasn't working for me either. Maybe I'm completely misunderstanding, but I thought the ~ notation would allow me to import scss from a package in /node_modules.

Any suggestions/clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Update: adding the setup from my webpack.config file (most of which is the default from create-react-app).

```
{
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [
              require.resolve('classnames-loader'),
              require.resolve('style-loader'), {
                loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
                options: {
                  importLoaders: 1,
                  modules: 1,
                  localIdentName: "[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]"  
                },
              },{
                loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
                options: {
                  // Necessary for external CSS imports to work
                  // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2677
                  ident: 'postcss',
                  plugins: () => [
                    require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
                    autoprefixer({
                      browsers: [
                        '>1%',
                        'last 6 versions',
                        'Firefox ESR',
                        'not ie < 9', // React doesn't support IE8 anyway,'
                      ],
                      remove: false,
                      flexbox: 'no-2009',
                    }),
                  ],
                },
              },{
                loader: require.resolve('sass-loader'),
                options: {
                  outputStyle: 'expanded'
                }
              }
            ],
          }
```

Comment: This appears to be in relation [webpack configuration](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1789) you may want to scroll from bottom up to find a solution there, essentially I'd check whether webpack is allowed to handle ```.scss``` files via ```resolve``` part of the configuration

Comment: Thank you - I've updated my post with what's currently in `webpack.config` - I it's already set up to handle .scss files.

Comment: One other thing - I'm also importing susy and normalize into my main styles.scss without any problem; it's only when I import slick-themes.css and slick.css that I have a problem.

Comment: Sorry if this is bothering, I have released a [react carousel slider](https://github.com/Carr1005/react-carousel-slider) component these days,
install it by `npm install react-carousel-slider`, don't need to import other things else, with default css style but still endeavors to provide flexibility for customizing css , maybe you could have a try : )

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I was struggling with this issue and I finally find the solution:

1. just go inside of your `node_modules` folder and find `slick-carousel` folder
2. inside of that find `slick.scss` and `slick-theme.scss` from slick folder and open them up
3. create two seperate files with names of `_slick.scss` and `_slickTheme.scss` inside of your style folders of your project
4. copy all from `slick.scss` and `slick-theme.scss` and put them in your newly created files ( `_slick.scss` and `_slickTheme.scss` )
5. import them in your `app.scss`file
6. now if you are using webpack like me, I'm guessing that you getting can't resolve `'./ajax-loader.gif'` error and can't resolve font error after that
7. in fact those files is been used by `slick-carousel` css it self and for that we can just simple go inside your newly created `_slickTheme.scss` and find these lines

```
/* Slider */

.slick-list {
    .slick-loading & {
        background: #fff slick-image-url("ajax-loader.gif") center center no-repeat;
    }
}

/* Icons */
@if $slick-font-family == "slick" {
    @font-face {
        font-family: "slick";
        src: slick-font-url("slick.eot");
        src: slick-font-url("slick.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), slick-font-url("slick.woff") format("woff"), slick-font-url("slick.ttf") format("truetype"), slick-font-url("slick.svg#slick") format("svg");
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }
}
```

8. comment them out

Answer (score 66):

you change to be this :

```
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";

import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";
```

delete **~**

Comment: Thanks mate, this worked.

However what does '~' in the import statement mean?

Comment: ~ it means to root folder, i think it works only if you installed the module globally. I'm really not sure of what i am saying though, it's only an assumption

Answer (score 50):

you might have missed this:

```
npm install slick-carousel
```

Comment: Fiddestick! That was exactly my case for this issue. I didn't realize that I had install reack-slick twice while focusing on documentation instructions. Some distractions... (=

Comment: Thanks! I completely forgot to install it. Helped a lot

Comment: Thanks, I've been stuck and this saved me.

Answer (score 34):

You Also need to install slick-carousel for CSS and fonts.
**That's the trick here.**
Cheers...

First, install `slick-carousel`

```
 npm install slick-carousel --save
```

If you are using yarn, you can use

```
 yarn add slick-carousel
```

Then import CSS files in your App.js file.

```
 import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
 import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to have appropriate loaders.
Use [style-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/style-loader/) in combination with [css-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/) for the CSS.
Use [file-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader) and [url-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-loader) in order to load the fonts and images linked within CSS files.

*[(Here are configuration settings for the file-loader)](https://www.chriscourses.com/blog/loading-fonts-webpack)*

So at the end, your **webpack.config.js** should contain something like this:

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
                loader: "babel-loader",
                options: {
                    presets: [
                        "@babel/preset-env",
                        "@babel/preset-react"
                    ].map(require.resolve)
                }
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
                {loader: "style-loader"},
                {loader: "css-loader"}
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/i,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'url-loader',
                    options: {
                        limit: 8192
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
            use: [{
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: '[name].[ext]',
                    outputPath: 'fonts/'
                }
            }]
        }
    ]
},
```

After that, you can simply import styles into your application entry point (e.g. */src/index.js*):

```
import 'slick-carousel/slick/slick.css';
import 'slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css';
```

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks :) Upvote @Mališa Stanojević

Answer (score 1):

It fails because you are importing css modules in your app, and styles from slick are not applied because they are getting cached.
I've fixed it in my project like below:

In your style.scss files put this

```
:global {
    @import 'node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick';
}
```

Comment: it will be app.scss in your case I bet

Answer (score 1):

You are missed installing a slick carousel. try this code

```
npm install slick-carousel
```

[Click here for more Details](http://%20https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-slick)

Answer (score 1):

you need to install `react-slick` CSS files without `~` sign like this:

```
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";

import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";
```

and you need to import them also in the component that is showing your **slick** slider

for example, if you have a **slider component ** that is going to be used in **Home component**, you need to import slick CSS files in Home too. it worked for me.

and if you are changing **direction** to `rtl`, you need to use `ltr` for slider

and check `slick-carousel` to be installed

Answer (score 0):

To import styles, make sure that you have installed slick-carousel first:

```
npm install slick-carousel --save
```

then:

```
import "~slick-carousel/slick/slick.css"; 
import "~slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";
```

> Note: But be aware slick-carousel has a peer-dependancy on jQuery
> which you, or your colleagues may not like to see in your console
> output, so you can always grab the CSS from there and convert it into
> any CSS in JS solution that you might be using.

This information was taken from [react-slick documentation page](https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/get-started).